# tool-tip in multi line chart js not working

Tags: javascript, charts

I have a multi line chart using the framework "chartjs" the problem is the tool tip code is not working but the scale label works fine.

below is the code

```
      var ctx = $("#reportContainer").get(0).getContext('2d');
             ctx.canvas.height = 300;  // setting height of canvas
             ctx.canvas.width = 1000; // setting width of canvas

        //call options to have the effect of displaying currency format

        var lineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {

            bezierCurve: false,
            scaleLabel: function (valueObject) {
                return 'Php ' + valueObject.value.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
            },
            tooltipTemplate: function (valueObject) {
             return  ' Php' + valueObject.value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
               // return valueObject.label + ': Php' + valueObject.value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
            }
        });
```

[image]

The Y axis works fine , it displays the "Php" and has "," but when I hover on point/s it doenst display the "Php" and ",".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replace the tooltipTemplate with this "multiTooltipTemplate".